# The Big Book of Proof

Tags: soft-question

Some time ago, I came across an anecdotal story about the "Big Book of Proofs" that God always keeps up in the heaven, which records valid proofs of all theorems in the world. A noted mathematician was quoted as saying that if he was to die tomorrow, the first thing he would do is to take a look at the book, since he had such burning questions about some math proofs.

Kindly let me know if you happen to know the source and the person's name; I would love to quote them in my writing. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the gentleman you're thinking of is Paul Erdős: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: Who is Paul Erdös? Do you mean Paul Erdős by any chance?

Comment: @AsafKaragila a simple correction/edit would be just fine, no need to play dumb :)

Comment: But... that's the only way I can be dumb! Please don't take that away from me! :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Who is this Paul Erdős? Do you mean Erdős Pál by any chance?

Comment: For the record, I'm referring to the gentleman with the Erdős number of $0$.

Comment: @TonyK: I didn't know him personally, so I can't say that he was my Pál. :-)

Comment: @TonyK, yes, most of this comment thread is all in good fun 8)

Answer (score 8):

Based on Erdős's idea of that book of proofs that God keeps in Heaven, another book, called [*Proofs from the Book*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642008550) was written by Martin Aigner and  Günter M. Ziegler.